# Get items from an array in localstorage and display them each individually using a button

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, random, local-storage

I've managed to get a user's multiple inputs to store into `localStorage` in an array and now I need to display the input randomly on click.  So basically someone just keeps clicking a 'generate' button to see each input randomly and individually. I need to get it to display what is stored in the array from localstorage (or elswhere) in a random and individual way. Possibly rotating in a text area.

Currently I have it displaying all at once instead of individually. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

```html
    <form>
      <input id="item" type="text" placeholder="Add New Favorite Here" >
    </form>
        
<div id="favul"><ul id="items"></ul></div>
   

<button id="favbutton1" style="width:100px" onclick="wipe()">Clear</button>
        
<script>
            
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
const input = document.getElementById('item');
let itemsArray = localStorage.getItem('items') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) : [];

localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray));
const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'));

const liMaker = (text) => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = text;
  ul.appendChild(li);
}

form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  itemsArray.push(input.value);
  localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray));
  liMaker(input.value);
  input.value = "";
});

data.forEach(item => {
  liMaker(item);
});

function wipe() {
  localStorage.clear();
  while (ul.firstChild) {
    ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild);
  }
  itemsArray = [];
};

</script>
        
        

<button id="favButton" onclick="copy()">Copy</button><br>
       

<script>
  
function copy() {
  let plot = document.getElementById("plot");
  plot.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
}
        
</script>
```

Comment: Where's your code? What's your ***specific*** problem? Have you made an attempt at a solution? Please read [How to ask a question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please may you share a [mcve] of the issue?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance guys but whenever I try to put sections of code, it renders incorrectly

Comment: It's ugly, I know

Comment: When you want to add code, you can indent if by 4 spaces and it will automatically render as code. Or, you can enter it as normal but then select it and click the `{}` button on the editor toolbar, which will do the indent for you. You can also click the `<>` button to create an executable version of your code in the stack snippet editor.

Comment: I'm trying to get it so a person can input stings that are saved to localstorage in an array and then they can click a button that allows them to rotate through each input in the array.  My problem is that I can't get it to display individually correctly

Answer (score -1):

If I didn't get it wrong side, random numeric number generator will solve your problem. You can simple your link your button and the number generator function between (0,length-of-array). Here is simple pseudo code written in `python`.

```
import random

your_array = [...]

def press_button(list):
    return your_array(random.randint(0, len(list)))
```

Comment: The question is not tagged with Python.

Comment: I appreciate your effort but Python isn't going to work here